# KMS Terminal: How to disable second screen, or how to force a certaion resolution?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, display, kms

I have two screens with different native resolution connected to my Gentoo/systemd machine. since the VTs try to mirror the outputs, they do not use the whole size of the higher resolution screen. I never use virtual terminals on the lower resolution screen, so I'd like to have them use the whole high resolution monitor.

If I disable the lower resolution screen with the video kernel command line parameter, I cannot switch it on in X11, since the kernel thinks the output is not connected. Nevertheless, on X11 I want to be able to enable the second monitor whenever I need it.

Is there an option on the kernel command line, in systemd, or somewhere I can't think of at them moment, to disable the virtual terminals on one output, to have different virtual terminals on different outputs (kind of multiseat), to force the vts to use the whole size of one connected screen, or to disable an output on virtual terminals in such a way that xrandr can reenable it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the virtual console resolution with fbset and set it to anything up to the resolution of the larger screen. The other screen will then only show the upper left area of the entire virtual console, and I do not know of any way to disable that. No side effects on X11 once you switch back to the VT it runs on.

E.g. to set all console VTs to 2560x1440, run the following in any one console VT:

```
fbset -a -xres 2560 -yres 1440
```